# Text doesn't show in boxes shipped-out from inside the TikZ source code

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, shipout

I'm trying to understand a certain aspect of the TikZ language by inspecting its source code. The code that I'm interested in is in the file `<tex installation directory>/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`.

For debugging purposes, I would like to export some Tex boxes that are created by the code. In light of the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384922/21685), I've sprinkled a dash of `\shipout` commands throughout the code. I've added auxiliary text inside the boxes to help with debugging. However, the additional text doesn't show on the page.

Consider the following simplified example. Write `\shipout\hbox{Hello, world!}` as the first line inside the `\tikz@finish` macro. This is the macro that renders the picture on the page, so it is always called. Now create a new file with the following simple TikZ picture of a straight line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \draw (0,0) --(1,0);
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf file does not contain the phrase 'Hello, world!' anywhere!

Comment: TikZ resets the font to `\nullfont`. Try adding `\normalfont` inside the `\hbox`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Like this: `\shipout\hbox{\normalfont Hello, world!}`? It doesn't work.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: However, this works: `\shipout\hbox{\font\myfont=ccr9\myfont Hello, world!}`. Thanks! Are the effects of the font change limited to the enclosing TeX scope? I don't want this to affect the surrounding TikZ code.

Comment: @EvanAad there is no need to use a font declaration of that form, just \normalfont would have been Ok, but font setting are always local in tex (although the font declaration `\font\myfont` you used there has some global effects as fonts are only loaded once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ resets the font to `\nullfont` inside its environment. Also it redefines `\selectfont` to choose `\nullfont`. Therefore, the font needs to be restored, if you want to output a box inside environment `tikzpicture` and friends.

The environment `pgfinterruptpicture` can be used as wrapper of the box contents to restore the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\tikz@finish{%
  \shipout\hbox{%
    \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
      Hello, world!%
    \end{pgfinterruptpicture}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tikz \draw (0,0) --(1,0);
\end{document}
```

First page:

> [image: Result, page 1]